# Is a US state's revocation of a business license not being federally appealable codified somewhere, or is there simply no law saying it can be?

Tags: us-constitution, new-york-state, appeal, federalism, tenth-amendment

While the US constitution does contain the Interstate Commerce clause, it is argued that revocation of a business license and dissolution of a business following a US state's legal process can not be appealed to a US Federal Court because (if I understand correctly) there is no place in the constitution that specifically says that it can be.

**Question:** Is a US state's revocation of a business license not being federally appealable codified somewhere, or is there simply *no law saying it can be?*

There is of course the [Tenth Amendment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tenth_Amendment_to_the_United_States_Constitution#Drafting_and_adoption) ratified on December 15, 1791, but it seems that when large sums of money are involved the ability to escalate appeals beyond the state would have been tested vigorously at some point. **Perhaps there's a specific, broad ruling** in addition to some simple rejections?

---

In the October 3, 2023 Amanpour and Company video [Journalist on Trump’s Civil Fraud Trial: “His Whole Life Has Been a Facade”](https://youtu.be/ZuVMCLdq9Ww?t=571) (cued at  09:51) "[David Cay Johnston](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Cay_Johnston)... a Pulitzer Prize-winning economics reporter" says:

> And there is no appeal -- should be no appeal to federal court because there is no federal issue here this is entirely a New York State issue. **States decide who gets to run a business under our system, not the federal government, because the founding fathers never thought about corporations and regulation when they wrote the Constitution.**

Answer (score 18):

**Question**

> Is a US state's revocation of a business license not being federally
> appealable codified somewhere, or is there simply no law saying it can
> be?

**Answer**

*Overview*

The way that the federal court system and the state court system interact in the United States is intricate and complicated. There is a legal basis for the bottom line conclusion that litigants in the case referenced in the question can't appeal to federal court and that it would be hard to challenge this particular kind of business regulation even prior to it becoming part of the court process if that had happened. But it isn't all laid out in one place.

But some of the answer comes from the federal case law of civil procedure, some of the answer comes from multiple federal statutes, and some of the answer comes from more than one provision of the U.S. Constitution.

*State court decisions can't be reviewed by federal trial courts*

The principle that a state court decision can't be appealed in federal trial court is called the [Rooker-Feldman doctrine](https://www.americanbar.org/groups/business_law/resources/business-law-today/2019-november/the-limitations-of-the-rooker-feldman/), which is part of the federal common law of civil procedure.

*State court decisions can't be reviewed by the U.S. Courts of Appeal*

The U.S. Courts of Appeal are creatures of statute, and there is not a statutory grant of jurisdiction that allows them to review the decisions of state courts. The relevant statutes are [28 U.S.C. §§ 1291, 1292, 1294. 1295 and 1296](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/28/part-IV/chapter-83).

*SCOTUS review is limited to federal questions*

In a case in which all state court appeals have been exhausted, there can be an appeal to the U.S. Supreme Court, but Article III, Section 2, Clauses 1 and 2 of the U.S. Constitution limits these appeals to federal law issues only, with certain select exceptions. It states:

> The judicial Power shall extend to all Cases, in Law and Equity,
> arising under this Constitution, the Laws of the United States, and
> Treaties made, or which shall be made, under their Authority;—to all
> Cases affecting Ambassadors, other public Ministers and Consuls;—to
> all Cases of admiralty and maritime Jurisdiction;—to Controversies to
> which the United States shall be a Party;—to Controversies between two
> or more States;—between a State and Citizens of another State,—between
> Citizens of different States,—between Citizens of the same State
> claiming Lands under Grants of different States, and between a State,
> or the Citizens thereof, and foreign States, Citizens or Subjects.
>
> In all Cases affecting Ambassadors, other public Ministers and
> Consuls, and those in which a State shall be Party, the supreme Court
> shall have original Jurisdiction. In all the other Cases before
> mentioned, the supreme Court shall have appellate Jurisdiction, both
> as to Law and Fact, with such Exceptions, and under such Regulations
> as the Congress shall make.

*First instance review of state non-judicial decisions in federal courts*

Sometimes a state and local government decision, that is not made by a state or local court, can be challenged in federal court, if the challenge is based upon a federal law in what is called federal question jurisdiction. [28 U.S.C. § 1331](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/28/1331) which states:

> The district courts shall have original jurisdiction of all civil
> actions arising under the Constitution, laws, or treaties of the
> United States.

But, a federal law defense to a legal action is not a basis for a case to be tried in federal court at the trial court level, pursuant to a federal common law civil procedure doctrine known as the [Well Pleaded Complaint Rule](https://www.fedbar.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/yld-jun15-pdf-1.pdf).

For example, an argument that a state's regulation of business entities violates the U.S. Constitution's "[dormant commerce clause](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dormant_Commerce_Clause)" doctrine would be a defense to an action to revoke a business entity's license to operate under state law, and so it would not be provide a basis to remove a case to federal court.

A facial challenge of such a state statute, rather than a defense to a state effort to enforce it, probably could be brought in federal court if an actual case and controversy were identified and the federal lawsuit were brought by a person with standing to raise the issue against a state official charged with enforcing the law.

*The impact of the Eleventh Amendment*

A case brought by a state government, however, can't be removed to federal court, and a case against a state government can't be brought in federal court, due to the [Eleventh Amendment to the U.S. Constitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eleventh_Amendment_to_the_United_States_Constitution). The text of the Eleventh Amendment states:

> The Judicial power of the United States shall not be construed to
> extend to any suit in law or equity, commenced or prosecuted against
> one of the United States by Citizens of another State, or by Citizens
> or Subjects of any Foreign State.

But it has been interpreted in a manner broader than its literal meaning to hold that state governments, as entities, are immune from suit in the federal court, unless their sovereign immunity is waived in a permissible manner (apart from lawsuits involving states over which the U.S. Supreme Court has original jurisdiction).

Local governments are not protected by the Eleventh Amendment and are treated as corporations instead for Eleventh Amendment purposes. This is why lawsuits in federal courts related to state governments are brought against a responsible government official in the state government, and not against the state itself.

*The Tenth Amendment is not directly relevant*

The [Tenth Amendment to the U.S. Constitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tenth_Amendment_to_the_United_States_Constitution#Drafting_and_adoption) states:

> The powers not delegated to the United States by the Constitution, nor
> prohibited by it to the States, are reserved to the States
> respectively, or to the people.

The Tenth Amendment is commonly viewed as an interpretive principle rather than an independent source of legal rights, although some efforts to bring lawsuits based upon the Tenth Amendment, usually invoking some notion of natural rights, have been attempted (mostly unsuccessfully).

To the extent that the Tenth Amendment is considered, however, its emphasis that the scope of federal power is limited and not the default rule favors not permitting federal court to have jurisdiction to consider the rulings of state courts.

**Footnote**

> In the October 3, 2023 Amanpour and Company video Journalist on
> Trump’s Civil Fraud Trial: “His Whole Life Has Been a Facade” (cued at
> 09:51) "David Cay Johnston... a Pulitzer Prize-winning economics
> reporter" says:
>
> "And there is no appeal -- should be no appeal to federal court
> because there is no federal issue here this is entirely a New York
> State issue. **States decide who gets to run a business under our
> system, not the federal government, because the founding fathers never
> thought about corporations and regulation when they wrote the
> Constitution.**"

For what it is worth, the bottom line conclusion is correct, and the fact this legal issue arises under state and not federal law is an important part of that analysis.

But the sentence in bold, even if it is an accurate statement of 18th century constitutional law, is misleading.

The federal government can and routinely does regulate corporations and who gets to run a business. Federal securities laws, federal banking laws, and federal broadcasting laws, for example, do just that. Those federal regulations of corporations and who gets to run a business just so happen to not be at issue in Trump's New York State civil fraud enforcement case (unsurprisingly, because it was brought by the New York State Attorney General and not by a federal regulatory official).

The issue is what court has authority over litigation of which particular laws, not that Congress couldn't have enacted federal legislation of the kind at issue in the business license part of Trump's New York State civil fraud enforcement case.

Answer (score 6):

I will assume you are asking about a court-ordered revocation of a business licence, given that you are talking about an appeal.

The answer to your question then lies in the relationship between state courts and federal courts (also discussed at [this Q&A](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/87110/46948)).

An order by a state court is only appealable to the state appellate courts, not to federal courts of appeal. The state court system only intersects with the federal court system at the Supreme Court of the United States.

The quote you extract comes to the correct conclusion, but for the wrong reason. Johnston says:

> And there is no appeal -- should be no appeal to federal court because there is no federal issue here this is entirely a New York State issue.

The reason there is no appeal to federal court is because the trial decision was a state court trial decision.

Even if there were a federal issue, the decision of the state trial court (in New York, this is the New York Supreme Court) is only appealable to the New York State Court of Appeals. And from there, to the Supreme Court of the United States if there remains a federal issue.

Also, unless federal courts have been given exclusive jurisdiction over a matter, state courts are generally competent to answer questions of federal law. Nothing is anomalous about a state court deciding a case that turns on a question of federal law or even of the federal constitution. A party must request removal to federal court if they want the case decided in the federal court system.

Answer (score 3):

One point here worth mentioning is the US is not structured the same way as many other countries. For most other nations, the individual "states" are merely provinces: subdivisions of (and subject or subordinate to) the larger national government.

The United States, though, is a **federal** system. State governments are completely independent bodies from the federal (national-level) government, each with their own constitution, laws, and court systems. Through the course of a few generations this has come to more closely resemble other nations with stronger central governments, but the underlying structure is what it is. In fact, in some respects the US federal government more resembles the European Union government than that of any of its member nations.

This dynamic directly matters for the question at hand. In the EU, certain things just don't make sense to go "up" from one nation's court system into the EU court, because that's just not part of the EU's mandate. In the same way, the federal United States government does not concern itself with *or even have any authority over* certain matters, rather leaving them to each state to decide how they should be handled.